# Heavily unbalanced/skewed data clusters

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means, alteryx

I am facing some issues with my k-means clustering results on Alteryx. I am trying to conduct topic modelling on my data set of around 5000 text descriptions. After data cleaning, parsing and removing stop words and common words, I created a Document Term Matrix of 20 words and around 5000 documents.

After running K-Means Clustering on Alteryx, no matter how many clusters I indicated, there will always be only 1 document in all clusters except one with all the rest. For example:

### 2 Clusters

- Cluster 1: 19 words
- Cluster 2: 1 word

### 3 Clusters

- Cluster 1: 18 words
- Cluster 2: 1 word
- Cluster 3: 1 word

### 5 Clusters

- Cluster 1: 16 words
- Cluster 2: 1 word
- Cluster 3: 1 word
- Cluster 4: 1 word
- Cluster 5: 1 word

This clustering behavior happens no matter how many clusters I indicated. Looking for some help to shed some light and identify if these results would mean my data has problems or if I did not use the correct settings?

Comment: Why only 20 words? Are you using tf-idf? Are you clustering words or documents? Some more details on your method might help. However, it might really just be the data...

Comment: hi @user3658307 i calculated the frequency of occurrence of every word in the data set and took the top 20 most commonly used words (after removing stop words and other industry lingo). I am not sure if that was a form of tf-idf?

Comment: Are you implementing some particular algorithm from somewhere? Can you post more info, e.g. what are the 20 words, what are in the documents (e.g. books, newspapers; what categories are there, etc...)? That might help diagnose the problem. Also, I suggest understanding [tfidf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) if you are not familiar with it because that doesn't sound like what you are doing. It might help too.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at your data after preprocessing?

Probably many documents are now empty, or contain just one word.

The is not much left except finding the common words.